# How to set change a state on button click in react js.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, response

Iam trying to open a pop up on successful api response the problem is if I close it it does not opens again where as api is giving status 200 what i want is whenever there is status 200 it should open the modal again and again. for now it opens it for the first time when user clicks on the button.

My Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  FormCardComponent,
  ModalComponent,
  TextInputComponent,
} from "../../../components/index";
import { NUM_REGEX } from "../../../common/constants/variables";
import CountryCodes from "../../../common/countryCodes";
import countryCodes from "../../../common/countryCodes";
import IntlMessages from "../../../common/constants/IntlMessages";

export default class Comp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      status: false,
      email: "",
      number: "",
      address: "",
      error: "",
      errorNumber: "",
      code: "",
      selectedCode: "DK",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const user = this.props.user;
    this.setState({
      email: user?.user?.email || user?.data?.user?.email || "",
      // this.props.user.data.user.email || "",
      number: user?.user?.phone_number || user?.data?.user?.phone_number || "",
      address: user?.user?.address || user?.data?.user?.address || "",
      error: "",
    });
  }

//here iam updating my state
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.verifyPno !== this.props.verifyPno) {
      if (!this.props.verifyPno.status) {
        this.props.alertPopUp({
          open: true,
          type: "error",
          text: ["An error has occured"],
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          status: !this.state.status,
          isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
        });
      }
    }
  }

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
    });
  };

  handleNumberInput(e, name) {
    const re = /[0-9]+/g;
    if (e.target.value === '' || re.test(e.target.value)) {
      this.setState({ [name]: e.target.value, error: "", errorNumber: "" });
    }
}

  submit = () => {
    if (this.state.email.length < 1) {
      this.setState({ error: "Email is Required" });
      return;
    }
    if (this.state.address.length < 1) {
      this.setState({ error: "Address is Required" });
      return;
    }
    const { email, address } = this.state;
    const auth = this.props.user.data.user.access_token;
    this.props.updateEmailPhone({
      email,
      address,
      auth,
    });
  };

  submitPhoneNumber = () => {
    if (this.state.number.length < 1) {
      this.setState({ errorNumber: "Phone Number is Required" });
      return;
    }
    const { number } = this.state;
    let pnumber = `${this.props.user.data.user.country_code}${number}`;
    const auth = this.props.user.data.user.access_token;
    this.props.verifyPhoneNumber({
      pnumber,
      auth,
    });
  };

 
  render() {
    const { status } = this.state;
    const user = this.props.user;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {status ? (
          <ModalComponent
            isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
            toggle={this.toggleModal}
            className="customModel"
            size="md"
            body={
              <React.Fragment>
                <div className="modal-col">
                  <div className="row">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="close"
                      onClick={() => this.toggleModal()}
                    >
                      <i className="fal fa-close"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="container pl-3 pt-5 pb-3">
                    <h3>
                      <IntlMessages id="sms.heading" />
                    </h3>
                    <p>{<IntlMessages id="sms.paragraph" />}</p>
                    <div className="row">
                      <div
                        className="input-group mb-3 form w-100"
                        style={{ paddingLeft: "20px", paddingRight: "20px" }}
                      >
                        <TextInputComponent
                          className="w-100"
                          name="code"
                          value={this.state.code}
                          placeholder="Indtast kode her"
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            this.setState({
                              code: e.target.value,
                              codeError: "",
                            });
                          }}
                        />
                        <small className="text-danger my-0 py-0">
                          {this.state.error}
                        </small>
                      </div>
                      <div className="row">
                        <div
                          className="col d-flex justify-content-start"
                          style={{ paddingLeft: "40px" }}
                        >
                          <button
                            className="btn-danger"
                            onClick={this.resendSms}
                          >
                            <IntlMessages id="sms.resend" />
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <div
                          className="col d-flex justify-content-end"
                          style={{ paddingRight: "40px" }}
                        >
                          <button
                            className="btn btn-success button-margin"
                            onClick={this.submitSms}
                          >
                            <IntlMessages id="sms.submit" />
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </React.Fragment>
            }
          />
        ) : null}
        <div className="col-lg-4">     
          <form className="form bg-white p-3 mb-3">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-4 mr-0">
                <label>
                  <IntlMessages id="profile.emailbox.field.code" />
                </label>
                <select className="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
                  <option>
                    {user?.user?.country_code ||
                      user?.data?.user?.country_code ||
                      0}
                  </option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div className="col-8 ml-0 pl-0">
                <TextInputComponent
                  label={
                    <IntlMessages id="profile.emailbox.field.mobilenumber" />
                  }
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Mobilnummer"
                  value={this.state.number}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.handleNumberInput(e, "number");
                  }}
                  maxLength={user?.user?.phone_number_digits ||user?.data?.user?.phone_number_digits}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <small className="text-danger my-0 py-0">
              {this.state.errorNumber}
            </small>
            <div className="form-group">
              <div className="divider"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group mb-0 text-right">
              <button
                className="btn btn-default"
                type="button"
                onClick={this.submitPhoneNumber}
              >
                {<IntlMessages id="profile.button.update" />}
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: On which button submit you are having problem?

Comment: `this.props.alertPopUp(...)` suggests the popup state should be managed by the parent component, not by the component you're showing to us. The modal's close button toggle's local state instead of sending a "close" message to the parent, so I'm not surprised things go out of sync.

Comment: you can see in component did update where i have set the state

Comment: i have added coment to the section where the state is to be updated